# Merge arrays (PHP)

Tags: php, arrays, merge

How combine arrays in this way?

source:

```
Array
(
   [0] => Array
       (
           [id] => 3
           [title] => book
           [tval] => 10000
       )
   [1] => Array
       (
           [id] => 3
           [title] => book
           [tval] => 1700
       )
   [3] => Array
       (
           [id] => 27
           [title] => fruit
           [tval] => 3000
       )

.......

)
```

result:

```
Array
(
   [0] => Array
       (
           [id] => 3
           [title] => book
           [tval] => 10000,1700
       )
   [1] => Array
       (
           [id] => 27
           [title] => fruit
           [tval] => 3000
       )
.......

)
```

please help to solve this problem,
thanks!!!
sorry for bad english(

Comment: Try `array_walk()` http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk.php

Comment: Please use `var_export` instead of `print_r`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work:

```
$result = array();
foreach($array as $elem) {
    $key = $elem['id'];
    if (isset($result[$key])) {
        $result[$key]['tval'] .= ',' . $elem['tval'];
    } else {
        $result[$key] = $elem;
    }
}
```

This basically groups elements by `id`, concatenating `tvals` (separated by `,`).

Comment: @Vadim in what way does it not work properly? Please appreciate when people take time off to help you and you appreciate yourself by being more helpful so that others can help you.

Comment: as result only one array with empty(comma separated) [tval]

Answer (score 0):

Simply building slightly on user576875's method:

```
$a = array ( 0 => array ( 'id' => 3,
                          'title' => 'book',
                          'tval' => 10000
                        ),
            1 => array  ( 'id' => 3,
                          'title' => 'book',
                          'tval' => 1700
                        ),
            3 => array  ( 'id' => 27,
                          'bcalias' => 'fruit',
                          'tval' => 3000
                        )
          );

$result = array();
foreach ($a as $elem) {
    $key = $elem['id'];
    if (isset($result[$key])) {
        $result[$key]['tval'] .= ',' . $elem['tval'];
    } else {
        $result[$key] = $elem;
    }
}
$result = array_merge($result);

var_dump($result);
```

gives a result of:

```
array
  0 => 
    array
      'id' => int 3
      'title' => string 'book' (length=4)
      'tval' => string '10000,1700' (length=10)
  1 => 
    array
      'id' => int 27
      'bcalias' => string 'fruit' (length=5)
      'tval' => int 3000
```

The only real difference is the array_merge() to reset the keys

Comment: @Vadim - Glad to see you gave the credit to user576875
... all I did was a demonstration that his method worked

Comment: `array_values()` could have been used too :-)

Comment: @user576875 - True enough, I was just using it to after the proof that your code worked