# How to merge two arrays with same id in PHP?

Tags: php, arrays, merge

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Merge arrays (PHP)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4843263/merge-arrays-php)

This is aray my array how i merge array with his 'panid'.
same 'panid' please see array and required output.

show below array the 2 array contain same 'panid' but it's ingredient are different.
so i will merge this 2 array in one array with merge his ingredient.

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
    (
        [userid] => 62
        [panid] => 5
        [recipeid] => 13
        [ingredients] => 10 Kilos,1 Gram
        [panname] => XYZ
    )

    [1] => stdClass Object
    (
        [userid] => 62
        [panid] => 5
        [recipeid] => 12
        [ingredients] => 150 Gram,15 Pcs
        [panname] => XYZ
    )

    [2] => stdClass Object
    (
        [userid] => 62
        [panid] => 3
        [recipeid] => 15
        [ingredients] => 100 Gram,10 Pcs
        [panname] => ABC
    )
)
```

Require Output :

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
    (
        [userid] => 62
        [panid] => 5            
        [ingredients] => 10 Kilos,1 Gram,150 Gram,15 Pcs
        [panname] => XYZ
    )

    [1] => stdClass Object
    (
        [userid] => 62
        [panid] => 3          
        [ingredients] => 100 Gram,10 Pcs
        [panname] => ABC
    )
)
```

Answer (score 1):

PHP has some great datastructure classes you can use for this. Extending the [`SplObjectStorage`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.splobjectstorage.php) class to override the attach method, you can update your list of recipes however you like. You will likely have to do more sanity checking than I've done, but here's a fairly simple example:

```
class RecipeStorage extends SplObjectStorage
{
    /**
     * Attach a recipe to the stack
     * @param object $recipe
     * @return void
     */
    public function attach(object $recipe)
    {
        $found = false;
        foreach ($this as $stored => $panid) {
            if ($recipe->panid === $panid) {
                $found = true;
                break;
            }
        }

        // Either add new recipe or update an existing one
        if ($found) {
            $stored->ingredients .= ', ' . $recipe->ingredients
        } else {
            parent::attach($recipe, $recipe->panid);
        }
    }
}
```

You can use all of the methods available in [`SplObjectStorage`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.splobjectstorage.php) and add new recipes without having to think about merges.

```
$recipeBook = new RecipeStorage;
$recipeBook->attach($recipe1);
$recipeBook->attach($recipe2);

foreach ($recipeBook as $recipe => $id) {
    echo 'Pan Name: ' . $recipe->panname;
}
```

*This is completely untested, but it should give you some idea how to proceed.*

Comment: But it thrown error :

Catchable fatal error: Argument 1 passed to RecipeStorage::attach() must be an instance of object, instance of stdClass given, called in /home6/panchsof/public_html/dinnerrush/recipe.php on line 63 and defined in /home6/panchsof/public_html/dinnerrush/recipe.php on line 10

Comment: @GKumar00 I said it was untested. You're going to have to make it fit your data; I can't hold your hand the whole way...

Comment: sorry for this. okay.  bye thanks.